# Mongoose.js nested object query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so this is simple but i'm slowly falling into madness, I got existing json imported to mongoDB :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5611acaca5ea5f7c5d1a1f41"
    },
    "abilities":[
        {
            "name":"name1"
        },
        {
            "name":"name2"
        }
    ]
}
```

in my app a character model :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var AbilitySchema = new Schema({
    name:String
});

var CharacterSchema = new Schema({
        abilities:[AbilitySchema]
});

var character = mongoose.model('character', CharacterSchema, 'character_collection');

module.exports = {
    Character: character
};
```

in my controller, my query:

```
Character.findOne({'abilities.name' : 'name1'}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);
});
```

It seem through my search that this kind of query {'abilities.name' : 'name1'} would be the way to go for nested object but all my tries end up returning the whole dataset (wich is a lot bigger than this abstraction) or null and i can't figure out how to query the attributes of my abilities and go down the hierarchy of that document.

Thanks, Max.